# Como inserir HTML com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Qual a maneira mais simples de se inserir HTML em um elemento por meio do Javascript?

Comment: para quem esta começando eu sugiro umas "aulinhas" nesse site http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp me ajudou bastante no inicio

Answer (score 8):

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
element.innerHTML = '<b>Hello World!</b>'
```

Mas note que isso cria a possibilidade de falhas de segurança se o HTML que você quer inserir não for estático (isso é *especialmente* verdade se o usuário puder controlar parte do conteúdo que você quer inserir), mas é difícil postar uma versão mais segura do código acima sem saber exatamente como é a cara do HTML que você quer inserir.

Comment: Se você editar a sua pergunta e postar um exemplo de como é o HTML que você quer inserir, eu posso editar a minha resposta para mostrar como fazê-lo seguramente.

Comment: seu exemplo de código é bem simples, se é o "mais" simples só se fizer com 1 linha de código, +1 pela simplicidade(eficiência) do código

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       function addNewBtn(){
          $("body").append("<button>Outro Botão adicionado</button>");
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <button onclick="addNewBtn()">Adicione outro botão !</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Biblioteca Jquery é uma forma extremamente rápida, limpa e semanticamente elegante de manipular o DOM (Document Object Model), consulte a documentação da API http://api.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Use ``` `` ```para delimitar uma string em html

```js
var html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>
<p>In this example, we center the navigation links and add a border to the navigation bar.</p>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
`;
$('#html').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="html"></div>
```

Comment: Olá, na implementação acima vc tem o arquivo HTML já gerado e está inserindo mais informações? Ou ele gera seu HTML? Precisava utilizar informações que tenho em um portal para gerar um HTML que servirá como um relatório para o usuário. Preciso montar esse HTML dinamicamente. Já tinha visto um exemplo assim, tentei fazer mas ele não gera o arquivo, se puder me explicar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1):

**Se usar Jquery**
e o conteúdo for dinâmico

```
$( "#nomedaDiv" ).load( "teste.html" );
```

[Jquery (função load)](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que utilizar algumas funções do javascript é a melhor opção. Utilize por exemplo:

```
var divEl = document.createElement("div")
var textEl = document.createTextNode("Meu texto vai aqui")
divEl.appendChild(textEl)

document.getElementById("meu_target").appendChild(divEl)
```

Podes ver um exemplo neste fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tetbdkpe/

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira pouco convencional seria herdar a propriedade innerHtml a partir da interface HtmlElements.

**Por exemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Example Custom Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    .alert {
        padding: 1rem;
        margin: 1rem;
        display: flex;
        align-self: center;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
<script>
    class MyApp extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
            this.render();
        }

        render() {
            this.alerts = [
                'primary',
                'secondary',
                'success',
                'danger',
                'warning',
                'info',
                'light',
                'dark'];

            this.innerHTML = ` ${this.alerts.map(item => `
                <div class="alert alert-${item}" role="alert">
                            A simple ${item} alert—check it out!
                </div>
            `).join('')}`;
        }
    }
    window.customElements.define('my-app', MyApp);
</script>

</html>
```